# Can't Figure Out The Convert String

Tags: php

Can anyone help? I am trying to get INR price, But it only gives me USD

(string) convert - return pricing info in terms of another currency. I don't know how to.

```
<?php  
error_reporting(0);
$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result1 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$live_price = json_decode($result1, true);
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps if you hit it hard? Use a hammer?

Comment: On a more serious note: Your question is lacking specifics. Show us some code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve]. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: i am sorry i don't understand all of these. I am completely new in to coding and trying to learn how it works.

Comment: @Roy being new only excuses you so much.  It's not an excuse for not taking the time to write out a proper question and including context about your problem.

Comment: @Devon I guess you beat me to it :)

Comment: that's the problem. It took me an hour to figure out to enter the code in the box and i still couldn't get it right. I really apologize. But i will soon learn how this medium works.

Comment: Coinmarketcap uses an API with simple *get* requests. `echo file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/');` brought me more info than your attempted curl request. But that is mainly because I `echo` it. You don't. You set a variable... and that's it.

Comment: @Xorifelse can you show me the exact code how to. I know nothing about coding. How i managed to get that was days of work and through youtube and google. If you can give the exact line of code and where to place it. I used this is the <span>$ <?php echo $live_price['data']['1']['quotes']['INR']['price']['convert'];?></span> for price display.

Answer (score 0):

The request: `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/` gives the following JSON:

```
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17140537.0, 
        "total_supply": 17140537.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 6780.98, 
                "volume_24h": 3704860000.0, 
                "market_cap": 116229638586.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -0.42, 
                "percent_change_24h": -0.03, 
                "percent_change_7d": 2.62
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1531177530
    }, 
    etc...
```

Meaning, to go through all the values:

```
foreach($live_price['data'] as $mainkey => $index){
  foreach($index as $k => $v){
    if($k == 'quotes'){
      $v = $live_price['data'][$mainkey]['quotes']['USD'];
      echo $v['price'];
    } else {
      echo "Hi, I'm index as '$k' and my value is '$v'";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: slowly starting to understand this. But where is the convert string in it. Because by default the USD price is displayed with the above code. But there is something called String "convert" that coinmarketcap needs so that i could display the "INR" rupees price.

Comment: You might want to make a [different request](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) then

Comment: you're quite helpful. Thank you so much and i really appreciate. If i could just get the idea how the convert string works and where and how to place it on my code that i created. I could simply display the INR. Guess this coding business is not my cup of tea.

Comment: Again, simple matter of [changing the request](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=INR) to the API. So in my example I use `$live_price['data'][$mainkey]['quotes']['USD']` Change `USD` to `INR` to get that array's result.

Comment: yeah i tried that. But what worked was changing the URL to https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=INR

Answer (score 0):

Change $url to this:
`$url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=INR';`

It will give you both 'USD' and 'INR'.

Comment: wow that worked thanks. But some displays INR and some doesn't any reason why. Can i just get INR?

Comment: you're genius that simply worked. Thanks so very much

Comment: @Roy Nothing special, just try to search for documentation before coding :)
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/